# flexlm error on solaris

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I'm configuring a solaris server to be used with flexlm license system.
My software provider provided the script to install Flexlm, and I have its license.

I launched the script, which asks me for the path for the default installation, the path for the license, and at the end it says that the license is installed well.

The problem is the response when the script launches "lmgrd", which is:

nohup: (path of the installation)...lmgrd: Invalid argument
I'm stuck with this.

Can anyone give me some advise to work around this problem?
It's my first try with Flexlm on a non-windows machine and everything appears much more complicated than the straightforward installat

Answer (score 0):

The first question I would ask is "does the path exist on *that* server?"
Can you `cd /path/to/your/installation` and does that work?

The next question I would ask is; "Is there a symbolic link in the path somewhere?"

For example, if you gave FlexLM the installation path of `/usr/local/my_app` and the `local` directory in `/usr` is really a symbolic link to `/mnt/local`...
...then you need to use `/mnt/local/my_app` for the installation path.

It's been about 10 years since I setup a FlexLM server on Solaris, but FlexLM implementations can be customized by the vendor that provides the software to you, so you might want to double-check with them.